# How many principal minors a 3x3 matrix can have?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, matrix-rank

I'm reading the book [Polarimetric Radar Imaging: From basics to applications](https://www.crcpress.com/Polarimetric-Radar-Imaging-From-Basics-to-Applications/Lee-Pottier/p/book/9781420054972)
On page 75, there's this claim:

$$T_3 = \begin{bmatrix}
 2A_0 & C-jD & H+jG\\
 C+jD & B_0+B & E+jF\\
 H-jG & E-jF & B_0-B
 \end{bmatrix}$$ 
As the coherency $T_3$ matrix in such a case is a rank 1 Hermitian matrix, it follows
that its nine principal minors are zero, with:
$$\bbox[yellow]{2A_0(B_0+B)-C^2-D^2=0}\\
 \bbox[yellow]{2A_0(B_0-B)-G^2-H^2=0}\\
 -2A_0E+CH-DG=0\\
 \bbox[yellow]{B_0^2-B^2-E^2-F^2=0}\\
 C(B_0-B)-EH-GF=0\\
 -D(B_0-B)+FH-GE=0\\
 2A_0F-CG-DH=0\\
 -G(B_0+B)+FC-ED=0\\
 H(B_0+B)-CE-DF=0$$

I am wondering because I know that a $3\times 3$ matrix has nine $2\times 2$ submatrices and so nine minors, but only 3 of them (the highlighted ones are principal minors)?!!

The others are only submatrices (not principals) and so the other six equations are resulted from $\Re{|A_{({1,3},{1,2})}|}=0$,$\Im{|A_{({1,3},{1,2})}|}=0$,$\Re{|A_{({2,3},{1,2})}|}=0$,$\Im{|A_{({2,3},{1,2})}|}=0$,$\Re{|A_{({2,3},{1,3})}|}=0$ , $\Im{|A_{({2,3},{1,3})}|}=0$

Knowing that when a $3\times 3$ matrix is of rank 1, the determinant of all of its $2\times 2$ submatrices ($2\times 2$ minors) should be zero not just the principal ones.

Comment: You are absolutely correct.

Answer (score 18):

For a general $3\times 3$ matrix, 
$$A =\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}\\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23}\\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}
\end{bmatrix}
$$ there is one third order principal minor namely $|A|$.

There are three second order principal minors:
$\begin{vmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12}\\
a_{21} & a_{22}
\end{vmatrix}$ formed by deleting column $3$ and row $3$.

$\begin{vmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{13}\\
a_{31} & a_{33}
\end{vmatrix}$ formed by deleting column $2$ and row $2$.

$\begin{vmatrix}
a_{22} & a_{23}\\
a_{32} & a_{33}
\end{vmatrix}$ formed by deleting column $1$ and row $1$.

There are three first order principal minors: $|a_{11}|, |a_{22}|, a_{33}|$ .

Comment: $\begin{vmatrix}
a_{22} & a_{23}\\
a_{32} & a_{33}
\end{vmatrix}$ formed by deleting column $1$ and row $1$.